# I want to reduce the speed of animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

Here is my code where I am animating a simple div. But the issue is, I want to slow down the speed when the **X** grows to full size as you can see it suddenly flashes and shrinks.

Can someone help me.

```css
html {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.loader {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: "";
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 8px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.loader:before {
  animation: animate 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.loader:after {
  animation: animate2 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) skew(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) skew(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to slow down the animation at the end

```
    animation: animate 5s infinite ease-out;
```

Comment: no ease-out makes it slow when the x shrinks down 2nd time at the end